# How to coerce data.frame objects to Genomic Ranges objects in R?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, genome

I have several bed files in R as data.frame objects. Now I want to find overlap between at lean two bed files by element-wise.

To be clarify my question, I need to make a test row by row in 1st bed files (already in data frame objects), so taking only one row of the data frame as query, then give it to the interval tree where interval tree holding 2nd bed files(but need to coerce GRanges objects first).

my data looks like :

```
   idx  chrom     start    End    name        score  p-value
    1   chr1      32727    32817  MACS_peak_1  8.69 1.150748e-11
    2   chr1      52489    52552  MACS_peak_2  4.26 2.347418e-11
    3   chr1      65527    65590  MACS_peak_3  4.19 2.386635e-11
    4   chr1      65773    65904  MACS_peak_4  2.02 4.950495e-11
    5   chr1      66001    66117  MACS_peak_5  5.66 1.766784e-11
    6   chr1     115700   115769  MACS_peak_6 10.30 9.708738e-12
    7   chr1     136389   136452  MACS_peak_7  4.26 2.347418e-11
    8   chr1     235352   235415  MACS_peak_8  4.26 2.347418e-11
    9   chr1     235636   235700  MACS_peak_9  5.66 1.766784e-11
    10  chr1     432895   432958 MACS_peak_10  4.26 2.347418e-11


f1 <- function(bed.1, bed.2){
  query<- GRanges()
  subject = bed.2
  for(i in 1: length(bed.1)){
    query<-bed.1[i]
    o <- GenomicRanges::findOverlaps(query, subject, minoverlap = 2L, algorithm="intervaltree")
    hitfrom_<-query[queryHits(o)]
    hitTo_<-subject[subjectHits(o)]
    pint <-pintersect(hitfrom_, hitTo_)
    return(pint)
  }
}
```

This is my code how to iterate set of GRanges objects in bed.1 and call findOverlap() function to find where is the overlapped GRanges. This code doesn't give me the results what I want. somebody help me out ?? Thank you

Comment: Could you provide an example of your 2 "data.frame"s?

Comment: Is there a reason that you're trying to do all this in R? bedtools is designed to find overlaps between bed files.

Comment: @heathobrien:  I know this process has been done by bedtools. What I want to do is to implement same things in R environment. Is there any simplest approach for doing this analysis in R ???

Comment: @heathobrien: example bed files, I have attached in original thread.

Comment: I guess you're looking for something like `find[or count]Overlaps(IRanges(df1$start, df1$End), IRanges(df2$start, df2$End))` from the "IRanges" package?

Comment: @Jurat : It sounds a lot like you're looking for `findOverlaps` from "IRanges" package after converting your 'start/end' of both your "data.frame"s to "IRanges" objects. Perhaps you could provide a more complete example with "df1", "df2" and, expected output?

Comment: @alexis_laz: thank you for your reply. Actually, the example you told me about, I tried. I wrote simple function for iterate over GRanges objects in bed.1. But it doesn't work out and didn't give me the expected results. expect results supposed to  be query GRanges object from bed.1 + overlapped GRanges object in bed.2. Please point me out where was my mistaken. Thank you !!

Comment: @Jurat : You don't need to iterate over "bed.1"; `findOverlaps` will search for overlaps for each interval in "bed.1". E.g. `findOverlaps(IRanges(c(1, 4, 9), c(3, 7, 12)), IRanges(c(0, 4, 6, 8, 12), c(3, 8, 10, 13, 15)))`. Also, in your `f1` function you `return` on the first iteration of your loop. To save an object from a loop you should not use `return` rather have an object to store results; e.g. `for(i in ..) the_object_to_be_returned_at_the_end[i] = f(object_to_manipulate[i])` instead of `for(i in ...) return(f(object_to_manipulate[i]))`.

Comment: @alexis_laz: it might sounds not wise to you. I have projects here that must be done in R. feature of this projects is look over each GRanges object in bed.1 one by one and do some meta analysis, when bed.1 is done, go to bed.2 repeat it. let's say, I have only two bed files in R, now I am analyzing each GRanges of bed.1 by row-wise and call findOverlap() function such as : overlap_1 <- findOverlaps(bed.1[1], bed.2, minoverlap = 2L), and overlap_2, and so on. so each GRanges object in bed.1 is varied, but take whole GRanges of bed.2 for calling findOverlap(). I am confused how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you don't need to operate row by row.

```
text1 <- "idx  chrom     start    End    name        score  p-value
1   chr1      32727    32817  MACS_peak_1  8.69 1.150748e-11
2   chr1      52489    52552  MACS_peak_2  4.26 2.347418e-11
3   chr1      65527    65590  MACS_peak_3  4.19 2.386635e-11
4   chr1      65773    65904  MACS_peak_4  2.02 4.950495e-11
5   chr1      66001    66117  MACS_peak_5  5.66 1.766784e-11
6   chr1     115700   115769  MACS_peak_6 10.30 9.708738e-12
7   chr1     136389   136452  MACS_peak_7  4.26 2.347418e-11
8   chr1     235352   235415  MACS_peak_8  4.26 2.347418e-11
9   chr1     235636   235700  MACS_peak_9  5.66 1.766784e-11
10  chr1     432895   432958 MACS_peak_10  4.26 2.347418e-11"

bed1 <- read.table(text=text1, head=T, as.is=T)

library(GenomicRanges)

bed1.gr <- GRanges(bed1$chrom, IRanges(bed1$start, bed1$End))
bed2 <- data.frame(chr=c("chr1", "chr1"),
                   start=c(30000, 130000),
                   end=c(60000, 200000), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
bed2.gr <- GRanges(bed2$chr, IRanges(bed2$start, bed2$end))
op <- findOverlaps(bed1.gr, bed2.gr)

op.df <- data.frame(que=queryHits(op), sub=subjectHits(op),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

bed1$que <- 1:nrow(bed1)
bed2$sub <- 1:nrow(bed2)

bed.n <- merge(bed1, op.df, by="que", all=T)
bed.n <- merge(bed.n, bed2, by="sub", all=T)
bed.n$que <- NULL
bed.n$sub <- NULL
bed.n
#    idx chrom start.x    End         name score      p.value  chr start.y   end
# 1    1  chr1   32727  32817  MACS_peak_1  8.69 1.150748e-11 chr1   30000 6e+04
# 2    2  chr1   52489  52552  MACS_peak_2  4.26 2.347418e-11 chr1   30000 6e+04
# 3    7  chr1  136389 136452  MACS_peak_7  4.26 2.347418e-11 chr1  130000 2e+05
# 4    5  chr1   66001  66117  MACS_peak_5  5.66 1.766784e-11 <NA>      NA    NA
# 5    6  chr1  115700 115769  MACS_peak_6 10.30 9.708738e-12 <NA>      NA    NA
# 6    3  chr1   65527  65590  MACS_peak_3  4.19 2.386635e-11 <NA>      NA    NA
# 7    4  chr1   65773  65904  MACS_peak_4  2.02 4.950495e-11 <NA>      NA    NA
# 8    9  chr1  235636 235700  MACS_peak_9  5.66 1.766784e-11 <NA>      NA    NA
# 9   10  chr1  432895 432958 MACS_peak_10  4.26 2.347418e-11 <NA>      NA    NA
# 10   8  chr1  235352 235415  MACS_peak_8  4.26 2.347418e-11 <NA>      NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

let's consider following reproducible example:

```
a <- GRanges(
  seqnames=Rle(c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3", "chr4"), c(3, 2, 1, 2)),
  ranges=IRanges(seq(1, by=9, len=8), seq(7, by=9, len=8)),
  rangeName=letters[seq(1:8)], score=sample(1:20, 8, replace = FALSE))

b <- GRanges(
  seqnames=Rle(c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3","chr4"), c(4, 3, 1, 1)),
  ranges=IRanges(seq(2, by=5, len=9), seq(4, by=5, len=9)),
  rangeName=letters[seq(1:9)], score=sample(1:20, 9, replace = FALSE))
```

then, overlap of two GRanges objects by element-wise:

```
ov <- as(findOverlaps(a,b), "List")
```

`ov` returns overlap hit-index vector as compressedIntegerlist objects.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called `makeGRangesFromDataFrame` for this very purpose:

```
makeGRangesFromDataFrame(df,
keep.extra.columns=FALSE,
ignore.strand=FALSE,
seqinfo=NULL,
seqnames.field=c("seqnames", "seqname",
"chromosome", "chrom",
"chr", "chromosome_name",
"seqid"),
start.field="start",
end.field=c("end", "stop"),
strand.field="strand",
starts.in.df.are.0based=FALSE)
```

If your start column is called something else than the defaults above, you must call it with `start.field="Start"` or whatever your column is called. Same for `end.field`, `strand.field` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `bed.1` and `bed.2` are both data frames, then this will work:

```
library(GenomicRanges)


colnames(bed.1)[c(2,4)] <- c("seqnames", "end") #GRanges insists on these column names
colnames(bed.2) <- colnames(bed.1)

gr1 <- GRanges(bed.1) #will work with the right column names
gr2 <- GRanges(bed.2)

#if you want the set of ranges overlapped by at least one range from each:
int <- intersect(gr1, gr2) #GRanges output
df.int = as.data.frame(int) #data frame of new ranges
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to start directly from the bed files themselves and import them directly into a GRanges object with the import function of rtracklayer:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("rtracklayer")
library(rtracklayer)
import("example.bed", format="bed")
```

This gives you your GRanges object without having to go through a dataframe intermediate.